# How does a ball that gets embedded in the outfield wall be handled?

Tags: rules, baseball

If the ball gets embedded in the outfield wall, what is the ruling?

[image]

Comment: It [happens fairly often](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p76UyUtmxFM) at Wrigley Field where the outfield wall is covered in ivy.  The [ground rules](https://www.mlb.com/cubs/ballpark/ground-rules) say it's two bases.

Answer (score 4):

This would be covered by the ground rules of wherever the game is being played, but a common treatment for such an unplayable ball would be to declare it a ground-rule double.

Answer (score 1):

High school baseball considers this a "lodged ball" and is considered a dead ball.

> A baseball that remains on the playing field but has become wedged, stuck, lost, or unreachable, is defined to be a lodged ball. If the ball impacts any object in the course of play, stops abruptly, and does not fall or roll immediately, it is considered lodged. It is a dead ball (5-1-1f-3,4; 5-1-1g-4)."

Source: [NFHS](https://www.nfhs.org/sports-resource-content/baseball-rules-changes-2023/#:%7E:text=A%20baseball%20that%20remains%20on,1%2D1g%2D4).